# In Elasticsearch how to give more priority to certain words in a phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named product in Elastic Search 7.4

Product has a field named title.

If I want to search all titles for blue watch I want to see all results which are blue watch or watch. I do not want to see results like blue t shirt. I want to prioritize the word watch.

i.e. How do a determine a noun in a search phrase and give it more priority than the corresponding adjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the boost parameter in elasticsearch

Boost parameter Gives higher priority to word "watch" than "blue"

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "title": "blue",
                        "boost": 1

                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": "watch",
                        "boost": 10
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the word "watch" to be a compulsory match simply put it inside must block and put "blue" inside should block to make it optional

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "watch",
                    "boost": 10
                }
            },
            "should": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "blue",
                    "boost": 1

                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to find a noun in your query and add higher boost, It should be done in your application level. Your server code such as python-spacy can be used to identify the noun and you can explicitly assign boost to it